# Detecting gaps in grid of divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, knapsack-problem, bin-packing

**EDIT** The solution has been found!

Here's a [blog post](http://www.drewdahlman.com/meusLabs/?p=218) about it, and here is the [Github repo](http://drewdahlman.com/experiments/perfectMasonry/)!

I am working on creating a grid of divs that is composed of multiple sized boxes, these sizes are set height's and widths - but are generated dynamically so each time the page is loaded there is a different grid.

**My problem** -
I tried using Masonry, but it winds up leaving gaps, also tried isotope. I am currently floating the elements left which is causing for the breaks in the layout.

**How it's built** - 
I calculate the screen dimensions and determine the best column count for the page ranging from 1 to 6, then based on that column width I calculate a "block" this block is essentially the perfect grid. Then I loop through my elements and give them either 1x1, 1x2, 2x2 dimensions.

[image: The Green spaces are blank areas - black are specifically sized based on their priority]

For reference here is another randomly generated grid
[image]

**My Question** -
Is there a good way to detect the missing spaces - currently I am placing my red and black boxes over another grid of my "blocks", which are green, for me to see where I am missing space. I've read about the knapsack packing problem, as well as bin packing problems - and I am having a hard time making sense of either of them.

**What I've tried** - 
I have attempted to calculate as I place the blocks to determine the best size but this still results in strange behavior. I have also tried using masonry and Isotope.

I am fine with a ragged bottom edge but the actual grid cannot contain any gaps.

**NOTE** - The grid is composed of a potentially endless number of elements - I have been thinking if I was to take and copy an element from the bottom area and place it into the missing areas I could avoid having to "shift" elements - I just need to know how to find that missing space.

Any help or pointing in the right direction would be great!

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9D6Qy/2/)

here is the base code for the js...

```
    (function() {
    GRID = function(el, sel) {
        var self = this,
            ran, ranSize, h, w;

        self.options = {
            el: $(el),
            sel: $(sel),
            cols: 1,
            block: {
                height: 0,
                width: 0
            },
            matrix: {
                w: [],
                h: [],
                t: [],
                l: []
            },
            row: {
                height: 0,
                width: 0
            },
            col: {
                height: 0,
                width: 0
            }
        };

/*
         * Size array
        */
        self.sizes = [];
        self.sizes[0] = [2, 2];
        self.sizes[1] = [1, 2];
        self.sizes[2] = [1, 1];



        self.setup = function() {

/*
             * Setup all options 
            */
            // block size
            self.options.block.height = (window.innerWidth / self.cols()) / 1.5;
            self.options.block.width = (window.innerWidth / self.cols());

            // row
            self.options.row.width = window.innerWidth;


            for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
                $(".grid").append('<div class="box"></div>');
            }

            self.size_boxes();


        }
        self.size_boxes = function() {

            if (self.cols() == 1) {
                self.options.sel.height(self.options.block.height);
                self.options.sel.width(self.options.block.width);
            }
            else {
                self.options.sel.each(function() {

                    $this = $(this);

                    ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * self.sizes.length);
                    ranSize = self.sizes[ran];

                    if ($this.hasClass('promoted')) {
                        ran = 0;
                    }
                    if ($this.hasClass('post')) {
                        ran = 2;
                    }
                    h = self.options.block.height * self.sizes[ran][6];
                    w = self.options.block.width * self.sizes[ran][0];

                    // box sizes
                    $this.height(h);
                    $this.width(w);
                });
            }
            $(".grid .box").height(self.options.block.height);
            $(".grid .box").width(self.options.block.width);
        }
        self.cols = function() {
/*
             * Determine cols
            */
            var w = Math.floor(window.innerWidth);
            var cols = 0;

            if (w < 480) {
                cols = 1;
            }
            else if (w > 480 && w < 780) {
                cols = 2;
            }
            else if (w > 780 && w < 1080) {
                cols = 3;
            }
            else if (w > 1080 && w < 1320) {
                cols = 4;
            }
            else if (w > 1320 && w < 1680) {
                cols = 5
            }
            else {
                cols = 6;
            }
            return cols;
        }
        self.resize = function() {
            $(".grid").height(window.innerHeight);
            self.options.block.height = (window.innerWidth / self.cols()) / 1.5;
            self.options.block.width = (window.innerWidth / self.cols());

            self.options.row.width = window.innerWidth;

            self.size_boxes();
        }

        self.setup();
        return self;

    };
})();
var _GRID = new GRID('.gallery', '.box');​
```

Comment: Hey man, I was trying to take a crack at this, but I was totally confused by your question... "placing red and black boxes over another grid of blocks" really threw me, also, I can't tell if you are assigning the dimensions (1x1, 1x2, 2x2) uniformly or if every block has a different dimension, but maybe this is just over my head :)

Comment: haha - so I have two divs positioned absolute. 1 grid is perfect boxes or "blocks" those block dimensions are calculated based on the number of columns and the screen width. this is the green grid ( mostly just for me to see where blank spaces are happening ). Now the other grid is where my elements that will be sized live. These get told to take up the space of 1x1, 1x2, & 2x2 of the "blocks" so 1 block wide, 2 blocks tall. What you see in the images as black and red are the sized elements, the green is the base blocks to show dimensions of the spaces to take up...

Comment: Are you trying to create something like this: http://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: This might not help me find a solution, but are the dimensions of each box fluid or fixed? For example, if you used 6 columns, is the base grid block width 16.66%? Or are you setting it to a pixel width based on the window size? Such as 280px if your window was 1680px wide.

Comment: @inorganik yes similar - this is using isotope - curious what layout method they are using...

Comment: @jackrugile they are px dimensions here ill throw up a jsfiddle

Comment: Masonry (Isotope as well, since they both run on Masonry) gets so close. I've looked into a couple mods of Masonry that claim to help with the vertical gaps, but none worked as expected. This is an open feature request on Masonry at the moment: https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/141

There is a mod that pushes Masonry in the opposite direction, where order of items is given all priority. This makes for even more vertical gaps though. You basically need the opposite of this:http://masonry-ordered.tasuki.org/demo-gallery/

Modifying Masonry might be a good start for what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep track of your "perfect grid" with an in-memory matrix of boolean values. This matrix stores whether spaces are filled or not. Whenever you place one of your boxes, you calculate which squares get occupied and update your matrix.

Comment: This is super close to what I have been thinking about doing, I get thrown off thinking of them in rows... would it be something like matrix[0] = [true,true,true,false], martrix[1] = [true,true,false,false] ? assuming this is a 4 column grid

Comment: This is a tricky one! Wouldn't you also need logic to calculate the matrix booleans based on the nature of float:left?

Comment: Yes, but you wouldn't have to think of them in rows. Depending on your matrix format you could set them one by one like matrix[row][column] = true, or matrix[column][row] = false.

Comment: Accepting your answer because you pointed me in the right direction :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're placing them in columns, simply place the divs in columns. For instance, if you've determined that there should be 4 columns:

```
<div>
    <div>Column 1, Div 1</div>
    <div>Column 1, Div 2</div>
    <div>Column 1, Div 3</div>
    <div>Column 1, Div 4</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>Column 2, Div 1</div>
    <div>Column 2, Div 2</div>
    <div>Column 2, Div 3</div>
    <div>Column 2, Div 4</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>Column 3, Div 1</div>
    <div>Column 3, Div 2</div>
    <div>Column 3, Div 3</div>
    <div>Column 3, Div 4</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>Column 4, Div 1</div>
    <div>Column 4, Div 2</div>
    <div>Column 4, Div 3</div>
    <div>Column 4, Div 4</div>
</div>
```

Of course, this will only work if the divs in each column are of equal height.

Comment: Potentially yes - issue is that they vary in height and width. Which could mean that one column could contain 4 elements while another contains 5 attempting to fill that area.